# Are the method calls inside if-checks "tested" and then "reverted"?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

I have suddenly forgotten how method calls inside if-checks works.

Example:

```
if (list.next() instanceof AClass) {
    AClass thing = list.next();
}
```

Still in this example, if `next()` iterates to the next object in the list, are the two items return by `list.next()` the same object ?

Generally, Are the method calls inside if-checks "tested" and then "reverted" so the same method call in the body equals the same as the one in the if-check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the implementation of the `next()` method. For example, if `list` is an `Iterator` then each call to `next()` advances the iterator, so the two calls in your code would give a different result (assuming they don't throw an exception). The same is true if `list` is a `Scanner`. Each call to `next()` would produce a different output.

On the other hand, if the `next()` method just returns some property of the `list` instance and doesn't change its state, multiple calls to it would give the same output.

Usually methods called `next()` change the state of the object on which they are called, but that's just a coding convention.

Comment: Ah thanks! Wanted to reply earlier, but had to wait 10 min. It seems to work properly now!

Answer (score 0):

If `list` is an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), you may need something like:

```
AClass thing = null;
Object n = list.next();
if (n instanceof AClass) {
     thing = (AClass) n;
}
```

in order to call `.next()` just once. Two subsequent calls will return two objects, because internal position is moved one step forward on each `.next()` invocation. There no any kind of "reversion" occurs.

Comment: Yes, thanks, had to cast it as AClass in the program, it works properly now!